# Add loading spinner to webview Android app

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am trying to add a loading spinner to show while the webpage loads.

Here is my code:

```
package com.wEgyptianpost;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import com.wEgyptianpost.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView view;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.admob_id);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);



        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);
        final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh,R.color.refresh1,R.color.refresh2);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mWebView.reload();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mWebView.stopLoading();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);





                    }
                },10000);
            }
        });
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        // Use remote resource
         mWebView.loadUrl("http:google.com");

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        // Use local resource
        //mWebView.loadUrl("file:android_asset/web/google.html");


    }



    // Prevent the back-button from closing the app
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

Here is my activity xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


        <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   </ScrollView>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/admob_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1851250777225639/8300259410"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />


</FrameLayout>
```

I added progress bar to the activity xml but I dont know how to link it to the main activity code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it with setting a webclient
for 
SET

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
{
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        } );
```

**To avoid `Ajax calls`**

Call this in activity

```
MyClient client=new MyClient();
mWebView.setWebViewClient(client);
client.setFirsttime();
```

and create a class in activity like this

```
public void MyClient extends WebViewClient(){
private boolean oneTime=false;
     public void setFirsttime(){
         oneTime=true;
       }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if(oneTime){
                 progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   onetime=false;
                 }

        }
           @Override
           public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
               view.loadUrl(url);
               return true;
               }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {

                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
```

On Ajax call `onPageStarted` called multiple times hence `progressBar` will not get hidden.

**Note: you have to call `client.setFirsttime();` every time when you are using `mWebView.loadUrl();`**

Comment: thanks but it keep spinning even after the page loads

Comment: thank you so much for the quick help finally it works horaaaay, but it works only on the first page can it be working on all pages? sorry if I am disturbing you

Comment: @MahmoudRagab where did you load second page or other page?

Comment: @MahmoudRagab if it the correct answer mark it as answer..:)

Comment: The webpage contains tabs that opens different webpages in the same site.Thank you so much I didnt test the last part but I will mark this as the true

Comment: @MahmoudRagab webpage contains tab must use the same web view or you have to set it again. And the last part is for ajax calls.it is not necessary for you

Comment: can you kindly look at this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307583/webview-client-error-in-tab-layout

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    WebView view;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private WebView mWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.admob_id);
         progressBar= (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
         progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);



        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipelayout);
        final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.refresh,R.color.refresh1,R.color.refresh2);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mWebView.reload();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mWebView.stopLoading();
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    }
                },10000);
            }
        });
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        //mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        // Use remote resource
         mWebView.loadUrl("http:google.com");

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());

        // Use local resource
        //mWebView.loadUrl("file:android_asset/web/google.html");
          progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but the last code to make it disappear you have attached it to the refresh button not the mWebview and this is what I am trying to reach

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                progressBar2.setProgress(newProgress);

                //newProgress maybe is 1~100


                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            }
```

Comment: thanks but it keep spinning even after the page loads